# Trying to transfer panda dataframe to mySQL dataset

Tags: mysql, pandas, dataframe

I was using panda to analyze the JSON file: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kpav-sd4t/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD

Everything is going well until I arrive at the end to transfer my information from panda to SQL.

I put:

```
df.to_sql('table', con, chunksize=20000)
```

but it results in

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1399             else:
-> 1400                 cur.execute(*args)
   1401             return cur

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute(self, query, args)
    209                 query = query.decode(db.unicode_literal.charset)
--> 210             query = query % args
    211 

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-a485028ed4c0> in <module>()
----> 1 df.to_sql('table', con, chunksize=20000)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
   1199         sql.to_sql(self, name, con, flavor=flavor, schema=schema,
   1200                    if_exists=if_exists, index=index, index_label=index_label,
-> 1201                    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
   1202 
   1203     def to_pickle(self, path):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    468     pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
    469                       index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
--> 470                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
    471 
    472 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype)
   1499                             if_exists=if_exists, index_label=index_label,
   1500                             dtype=dtype)
-> 1501         table.create()
   1502         table.insert(chunksize)
   1503 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in create(self)
    581 
    582     def create(self):
--> 583         if self.exists():
    584             if self.if_exists == 'fail':
    585                 raise ValueError("Table '%s' already exists." % self.name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in exists(self)
    569 
    570     def exists(self):
--> 571         return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
    572 
    573     def sql_schema(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in has_table(self, name, schema)
   1511                  "WHERE type='table' AND name=%s;") % wld
   1512 
-> 1513         return len(self.execute(query, [name, ]).fetchall()) > 0
   1514 
   1515     def get_table(self, table_name, schema=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1410             ex = DatabaseError(
   1411                 "Execution failed on sql '%s': %s" % (args[0], exc))
-> 1412             raise_with_traceback(ex)
   1413 
   1414     @staticmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py in raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback)
    337         if traceback == Ellipsis:
    338             _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
--> 339         raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
    340 else:
    341     # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1398                 cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
   1399             else:
-> 1400                 cur.execute(*args)
   1401             return cur
   1402         except Exception as exc:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute(self, query, args)
    208             if not PY2 and isinstance(query, bytes):
    209                 query = query.decode(db.unicode_literal.charset)
--> 210             query = query % args
    211 
    212         if isinstance(query, unicode):

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I connected to my server using

```
con = mdb.connect(host = 'localhost', 
                      user = 'root', 
                      passwd = 'dwdstudent2015', 
                      charset = 'utf8', use_unicode=True)
```

and

```
engine = con
```

I dont understand why it doesn't work

I have seen other examples but they don't translate

Comment: having a table named "table" might be the problem

Answer (score 1):

The `con` parameter of `DataFrame.to_sql` can be [either a SQLAlchemy engine or
an sqlite connection](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

If you are using MySQL (and the MySQLdb Python adapter), then you must connect
to it using an [SQLAlchemy engine](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/):

```
import sqlalchemy as SA
engine = SA.create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://{u}:{p}@{h}/{d}'.format(
                          u=USER, p=PASSWORD, h=HOST, d=DATABASE'))
df.to_sql('table', engine, chunksize=20000)
```

---

Notice that the error says

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

This SQL statement references [`sqlite_master`](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q7) because Pandas is assuming the
connection is to an sqlite database. Pandas will generate sqlite-centric SQL if
passed a connection. It will use SQLAlchemy to generate the SQL if passed an
SQLAlchemy engine.

Comment: it still doesn't work. It generated something like this:

OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'job_id' used in key specification without a key length") [SQL: 'CREATE INDEX ix_table1_job_id ON table1 (job_id)']